# Mysql PHP recomendation

Tags: php, mysql, email

Im buidling a reminder based on a mysql table data, my table looks like

```
Task Desc  Name Email
1    Task1 John John@mail.com
2    Task2 Eve  Eve@mail.com
3    task3 John John@mail.com
4    Task4 Mark Mark@mail.com
5    task5 John John@mail.com
```

in my php

```
$query = "SELECT desc, name, email FROM table";
$result_query = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error());
$num_results_query = mysql_num_rows($result_query);

if ($num_results_trad > 0) {
ob_start();
HERE I WRITE MY EMAIL

$Buffer = ob_get_contents();
    // get the output
    ob_end_clean();
```

After that i send the email. Now my problem is that i need to send a email to each user email once with all the Task assigned to him. If i do a loop i would be sending one email for each task or row, what im trying to do is to send one email, by example to John with Task 1 3 and 5, then to the second email found and so on with each user. Some one can point me in some direction?

Comment: Declare a variable outside the loop. Combine all the results needed into the variable using the loop and after the loop is finished, send it to that person.

Comment: My recommendation: don't use the mysql extension.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: search about mysql group_concat function .. that could solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop through this twice, one to aggregate all the tasks and then once to send out the email. In non-working php pseudocode:

```
$taskForUser = array();

// your query
$query = "SELECT desc, name, email FROM table";
$result_query = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error());
$num_results_query = mysql_num_rows($result_query);


foreach ($query as $result) {
    $taskForUser[$result['Email']][] = $result;
}

foreach ($taskForUser as $userTasks) {
    // email $userTasks at once.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this by using `GROUP_CONCAT`

ie

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT desc SEPARATOR ', '), name, email FROM table GROUP BY email`